# Missing python header files in Buffalo TeraStation NAS

Tags: python, nas

I recently received a TeraStation NAS and have been hacking away with it. Managed to get root access and install some simple programs, however some programs require dependencies which I have been failing to meet. I have tried both Sickbeard and SABnzbd and both fail because they need Cheetah.

> **root@TS-6VHL856:#** python SABnzbd.py
>
> The Python module Cheetah is required

Consequently installing Cheetah failed as well for missing headers:

> **root@TS-6VHL856:**/home/Downloads/libs/Cheetah-2.4.4# python setup.py install
>
> Not using setuptools, so we cannot install the Markdown
>   dependency
>
> running install
>
> error: invalid Python installation: unable
>   to open /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)

It is worth noting that this seems to be a very bare bones system with no package manager. (As far as I know)

Here is some general info I get from the command line:

```
root@NAS:/# uname -a
Linux NAS 2.6.31.8-atom_d510 #1 SMP Mon Apr 4 13:12:12 JST 2011 x86_64 unknown
```

---

```
root@NAS:/# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model   : 28
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D510   @ 1.66GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 1662.521
cache size  : 512 KB
```

How can I fix or work around this obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheetah compiles C extensions and in order to do this it needs Python header files. They can be obtained by issuing `sudo apt-get install python-dev` or `sudo yum install python-devel` on Debian and RedHat based distros. But you mentioned that your specific distro doesn't have any packaging infrastructure. In such case you can try to build Python from sources and reinstall it. Building from source will give you all the required things to build python C extensions for any other package you may want to install. If this is not feasible, for example if there is no gcc on your NAS, you can try to supply header files by copying them from `Include` directory of python sources to the folder with include files on the NAS, as a rule it's `/usr/include/pythonX.X`. Also you can build Cheetah on another machine with the same python version and architecture using `python setup.py build` and then copy Cheetah sources together with `build` directory to your NAS and issue `python setup.py install` there.

Comment: But he said: "It is worth noting that this seems to be a very barebones system with no package manager (AFAIK)."

Comment: @maurelio79 thank you for the reminder. I updated the answer with other options.

Comment: These seem like good ideas, i'll give them a shot and report back. Quick question tho, do you think i could get the header files from a VM? I have Ubuntu installed in a Parallels VM in a computer that also has an intel x86_64 chip.

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch You could have gave it a try, if Ubuntu had the same major version of python. But all currently supported versions except 10.04 LTS have Python 2.7 and judging from the error message you get your NAS has Python 2.6. You can get 2.6 sources from here http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tgz. Then just unpack and copy files from `Include` directory.

Comment: Awesome, I downloaded python for the proper version in my machine (2.6.2) and copied pyconfig.h from the "/PC/" folder  to the approprate include folder and tried again it it compiled! SABnzbd seems to be running from the command line even tho it is missing several modules - unrar, par2, _yenc ... - and I havent been able to access the web interface yet but the command line says it works! Any ideas how I can get gcc for this machine?

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch installing gcc isn't a trivial operation and might be unwieldy. I would suggest you to consider installing some flavor of major distro with NAS applications builtin, e.g. http://www.openmediavault.org/ or FreeBSD based http://www.freenas.org/